# If statement whether or not a sub has run

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, office-automation

I am trying to run a if statement to send an email if the sub has run and is successful.

The current code I am trying is

```
Private Sub SendButton_Click()

Call Populate

If Populate = True Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Doc.Save

    With EmailItem
        .Subject = "New ePRF Available"
        .Body = "I have completed a new e-PRF"
        .To = ""
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .attachments.Add Doc.FullName
        .Send
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set OL = Nothing
    Set EmailItem = Nothing
Else
    Call Populate
End If
End Sub
```

This is something I have never really done before so am very confused! Any help would be grateful!

Thanks

Comment: Your code attempts to call another routine called `Populate`, but you haven't included the code for that. Given your intended usage `Populate` would need to be a `Function`, not a `Sub`, and would need to return a Boolean value.

Comment: Hi Timothy, the Populate code is ginormous that is why I did not include it. But basically it runs through a large userform and checks whether or not every part of the user form has been filled in and if it has been filled in then fills a table with the given values of the user form. Would that be able to be used as a Function?

Comment: A function is just a sub with a return, create a boolean at the top of your populate function and make it true, at each check if it is not filled flip the bool to false, return the boolean and assign it to a variable in your sendbutton_click sub.

Comment: Thanks Warcupine. Im confused as to how that is going to help me with my problem? Sorry if I am being stupid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Populate` a function and have it return a boolean value, then check that value in `SendButton_Click`

I made a nonsense `populate` to show the general idea.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SendButton_Click()

If populate() Then 'Test the return
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Doc.Save

    With EmailItem
        .Subject = "New ePRF Available"
        .Body = "I have completed a new e-PRF"
        .To = ""
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .attachments.Add Doc.FullName
        .Send
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set Doc = Nothing
    Set OL = Nothing
    Set EmailItem = Nothing
Else
    Call populate 'This is probably not what you actually want, but hard to tell without seeing populate
End If
End Sub

Function populate() As Boolean 'specify the return type
    Dim returnval As Boolean
    Dim x As Boolean
    Dim y As Boolean
    
    returnval = True 'Start with true, if anything is false below flip the value
    
    x = True
    y = False
    'just showing the flow, you would be checking your userform values here
    If Not x Then
        returnval = False
    ElseIf Not y Then
        returnval = False
    End If
    
    populate = returnval 'return the value
End Function
```

Comment: I would set the return value of the function to `False` at the outset. It is best to assume that the code that follows will fail, in which case you wouldn't want to return a default value of `True`.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt You would then need to track them all together, any single instance of false here will flip it and keep it flipped. If you start with False, how do check each if's outcome and store it without constantly reassigning or introducing extra variables?

Comment: @KostasK. I don't think `populate` populates, I think it is checking if everything is populated. I guess I could remove the boolean at the top and just check the return without storing it.

Comment: I was wrong anyway -  run the function to check if the function run? lol That's why I deleted the comment. :)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I made an 'error' boolean which I set to True within the populate function. If the form is filled out correctly changes it too 'True'. Then in my 'SendButton_Click' sub ran the 'Populate' function and made an if statement `If error = False Then` run the email code (it wont fit on the comment). For some reason it will not send the email but will populate the table.

Comment: @Warcupine - according to the second comment below the question `Populate` "fills a table with the given values of the user form".

Comment: @Luke - If the `error` variable is in your `Populate` function `SendButton_Click` will not be able to read it. `SendButton_Click` needs to check the value of `Populate`, which you would set by using the same method as shown in the answer above.

Comment: okay that seems to have solved that problem. But now the opposite is happening. When the 'Error' is true it does not populate but will send the email. The code I have now is `if Populate() = False Then` run the email code `Else Call Populate`

Comment: `If Populate() Then` runs the function and tests for true, if it returns true it will email, the else statement should probably be a message box or something saying to complete the form, as it is now it just reruns `populate` which if it is hitting the else means it was returning false.

Comment: So I have updated my boolean to become 'complete' if they forget to fill something out then it stay 'False'. Each box they fill out correctly it becomes true. Then on the 'Send' button i have done the `if Populate() Then` run email code `else msgbox "you have missed something"`. What is happening is it is filling out the form because they have filled it out correctly, but does not send the email and comes up with the msgbox.

Comment: It has to be that I have missed a section to change the boolean to 'True' but I have gone through my code several times and can't figure it out!

Comment: update. So I tried setting the boolean to true at the start of the 'Populate' function to see if it worked then and is still populating the table and popping up with 'You have missed something' and does not send the email. Completely baffled now.

Comment: Update x2 I forgot to add at the end of the populate command `populate = complete` and it now works! Thank you both!